# Comlpex if statement not working in tibasic

Tags: ti-basic

I'm making a game that requires some complex if statements, here is the code that doesn't work

```
If K=25 and not(Y=1) and not([A](X,Y-1)=1)
Then
... Other Code ...
End
```

but it works when I do

```
If K=25 and not(Y=1)
Then
If not([A](X,Y-1)=1)
Then
.. Other Code ..
End
End
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

A problem with a condition such as `not(Y=1) and not([A](X,Y-1)=1)` (by the way you can use the `≠` operator instead of combining `not(` with `=`) is that *both sides* of the `and` in TI-BASIC are always evaluated (in contrast to how it works in many other languages). That means that if `Y` is actually `1`, then the expression on the right hand side is still evaluated but it fails with an `INVALID DIM` error. So, unfortunately, conditions like that must be split up.

Comment: Thanks, I split the conditions with labels, it looks nicer